# is Valid Golomb Ruler

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7

I want to write a function which can test whether a list of numbers is a valid Golomb ruler or not. I know how to do it in O(n^2) time (using nested for loops) but I am looking for a simple and more optimized way of doing it. I am trying to do it in python and my function takes a list of integers as argument.

A Golomb ruler is defined as a set :
[image]

Iff
[image]
(Wikipedia)

Comment: If there's a more efficient way, it's almost certainly not simple.

Comment: Remove the simplicity restriction then

Answer (score 0):

If this is [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM)-hard, then no one knows how to do much better than quadratic. I would be amazed if this weren't 3SUM-hard, but the hypothetical reduction looks as though it would be rather technical.

Answer (score 0):

it's my code in python which checks if the list of integers forms a rule of Golomb or not:

```
def is_golomb_ruler(ruler: list[int]) -> bool:
    marks_count = len(ruler)

    # check if first element is not 0
    if ruler[0] != 0:
        return False

    # check if contains negative values
    for item in ruler:
        if item < 0:
            return False

    # check differences table
    tab_diff = []

    for i in range(marks_count - 1):
        d = ruler[i + 1] - ruler[i]
        if tab_diff.__contains__(d):
            return False

        tab_diff.append(d)

    index = marks_count - 2
    diff_len = 2
    for i in range(index, 0, -1):
        for j in range(i):
            d = 0
            for k in range(diff_len):
                d += tab_diff[k + j]

            if tab_diff.__contains__(d):
                return False

            tab_diff.append(d)

        diff_len += 1

    # case of two identical marks
    if tab_diff.__contains__(0):
        return False

    return True
```

you find my repo of the [complete Golomb problem](https://github.com/AghribAbdessalem/GolombProblem_Metaheuristic_Project) solved by the metaheuristic method (Simulated annealing and genetic algorithms) here :

[GolombProblem_Metaheuristic_Project](https://github.com/AghribAbdessalem/GolombProblem_Metaheuristic_Project)